# Backpropagation gradient of the average

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative, gradient

In the [Pytorch Udacity course](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/master/intro-to-pytorch/Part%203%20-%20Training%20Neural%20Networks%20(Exercises).ipynb), the following is said at one point:

> To calculate the gradients, you need to run the `.backward` method on a Variable, `z` for example. This will calculate the gradient for `z` with respect to `x`

Following that, it is said in the course material that

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n x_i^2\right] = \frac{x}{2}
$$

I would have assumed that one could only take the derivative with respect to an individual $x_i$ since each of them is a separate random variable. However, then the solution would not make sense. I'd be very thankful for some clarity on how to arrive at $x/2$ in this case.

Comment: it seems wrong, it should be 2x/n; how did you get to this?

Comment: It is not my solution, but part of the course material

Comment: I have added a link to the source in my question, the relevant part is in the lower part of the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a vector, $z$ is a scalar. The derivative of a scalar with respect to a vector is [well defined](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Matrix_calculus#/Scalar-by-vector), it's the vector of individual differentials, i.e. $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_i}$. Executing for each $x_i$ yields $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_i}={2x_i \over n}$.

It seems that in your link $x$ is a matrix, and it is $2\times2$, (due to command `torch.randn(2,2,...)`), not a vector. But, the formulation in the notebook is treating it as if it is a vector, because we're talking about $x_i$'s. However, without loss of generality we can talk about a flattened version of $x$, which is of dimension $4 \times 1$. The `mean` operation in python takes the mean of each matrix element, so the script is really treating the matrix as if is a vector as we conjecture.

In conclusion, if you let $n=4$, $\frac{2}{n}x$ becomes $x/2$ as it is reported. But, it's a lucky coincidence I believe.

Note: If $x$ is $p\times n$, the derivative is $n\times p$, but this is a minor detail in this calculation.

Comment: Thank you! Then it also makes sense that the `print(x.grad)` command coincides with the reported solution.